# Remove certain characters from string

Tags: java, string, replace, character, replaceall

I want to create a program that gives the number of characters, words, etc... in a user-inputted string. To get the word count I need to remove all the periods and commas form a string. So far I have this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class WordUtilities
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in any text.");

      int a = s.length();
      String str = s.replaceAll(",", "");
      String str1 = str.replaceAll(".", "");
      System.out.println("Number of characters: " + a);
      System.out.println(str1);
      }
   }
}
```

But in the end I get only this:

```
Number of characters: (...)
```

Why is it not giving me the string without the commas and periods? What do I need to fix?

Comment: cause replaceAll exepcts a regex.. and `.` is a special symbol

Comment: @nachokk So what syntax do I have to use to remove the special symbols (. and ,)?

Comment: You'll need to remove more than just a period and a comma: colons, semicolons, dashes (as opposed to hyphens), apostrophes, double quotes... it's better to remove everything except what you want to count as a character.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight s = str.replaceAll("[.]","") from the other question fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[.]", "");
```

instead of:

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll(".", "");
```

As @nachokk said, you may want to read something about regex, since `replaceAll` first parameter expects for a regex expression.

**Edit:**

Or just this:

```
String str1 = s.replaceAll("[,.]", "");
```

to make it all in one sentence.

Comment: The `.` still needs to be escaped to `"[\.]"`

Comment: @JeremyMiller, not in a character class

Comment: @peeskillet - I stand corrected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of replaceAll cause [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.

So in code with replace is

```
 str = str.replace(",","");
 str = str.replace(".","");
```

Or you could use a proper regular expression all in one:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[.,]", "");
```

Comment: +1 for difference clarification

Comment: You should reverse your code because the explanation is for the latter case

Comment: @peeskillet i don't understand what you mean

Comment: The code at the bottom matches your answer description. So put that code first. Then you can use the OR for the relaceAll case. Make more logically sense and will make your answer flow more smoothly

Comment: I like your answer the best. People are so used to creating new strings, they forget you can just make the old string equal the modified string, but in which case, you should've used `s` instead of `str`